# Create new row in Database when we click on button

Tags: magento-1.9, database, image, addtocart, quote

By Default Magento create new **row** in Database in table **sales_flat_quote_item_option** once we click on **ADD TO CART**

We are giving an option of uploading custom image on Product image with help of custom module.

When we upload custom image on Product image [ [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) ] & click on **Add to cart**, we are saving **custom image** in Database in table `sales_flat_quote_item_option` & in column : `value` .

[image]

As like `Add to cart` button, we want same feature for one more custom button `Save Design`.

**Save design button**

```
<button id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >Save Design</button>
```

**i want to know which code is responsible for creating new row in Database after clicking Add to cart button.**

Where i need to look in **Module's Block or Controllers or Data or Helper or Model** ?

I can just copy **Add to cart** code and just rename to "**Save design**", but once we click on "Save design", i don't want to add Product to cart , I just want to create new row in Database.

Comment: i will give 100 bounty points if it worked for me......

Comment: do you want programeticlly addtocart ?? or just want to click addtocart button when someone click your button ??

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Thanks for reply, i dont want programtically,  in [LINK1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) or in [link2](http://stylebaby.com/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

we have `Add to cart` & `save design` button, right now if we just upload `image` and click on `add to cart` button, new row will create in DB

& image will save in Server. i want same feature for `save design` button also.

Comment: but for that you have to manually upload image ?? how I get image ??

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala yes after we upload image manually, than only i want to `save image in server` and `create new column` in Database.....

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala why i want to `save image` is because i want to send an `Abandoned cart email` for customer  and in email , we want to send `custom image` uploaded by customer..... we are doing this successfully if customer click on `add to cart` , so i need same feature for `save design` also......

Comment: So,  we can click programetically on uploadImage and addtocart when user clicks on saveImage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54728/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: Welcome back to magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Abdul please join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54728/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-murtuza-zabuawala

Comment: @BabyinMagento are you looking to "add to cart" without leaving the page?

Comment: @RyanScottCady right now when we click on a) `Add to cart`, it will do 2 things - 1) it will add product to cart 2) it will save the custom image in server & Database [ Custom image - it is image uploaded by user on product image in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) ] , now what i need is when we click on b) `Save design  ` button, i want to save image in server & Database, but i don't want to add products to cart.....

Comment: if you want have clarfications,please join here  : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54922/let-me-know

Comment: check `cartController.php`

Comment: @urfusion in cartController.php , can you please tell what code is reason to create new row, also how we can create new row after we click on `custom button` instead of `add to cart` button . but after clicking on that button it should't add product to cart.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below trick for that

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("button[title='SAVE DESIGN']").click(function(){
     openCustimage("UserImage");
     setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('.button.btn-cart').get(0).click();              
     }, 2000);  

    });    
 });
```

Comment: sorry, it didt worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for your support ,  as other user spent more time in helping me in [link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54922/let-me-know) , i awarded bounty for him, need your support like this as always.....

Answer (score 2):

You can try do something like this:

1. add new column in `sales_flat_quote_item_option` named eg
   `allowed_in_cart` as bool (true / false) with default false value.
2. Rewrite cart action app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php ::
   indexAction for don't display products with value `allowed_in_cart`
   as false.

   However better way is 'disable' cart when
   `allowed_in_cart` is false instead of only don't display products.
3. To `Save Design` Button add action change `allowed_in_cart` value to true for specific cart.

Comment: can you please join here : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54922/let-me-know