# dont add Product to cart when we click on ADD TO CART

Tags: magento-1.9

By Default , ADD TO CART will do 2 things.

**1**)Add Item to cart

**2**)Create new row in **sales_flat_quote_item_option** Table in **Value** column.

But We want to remove first feature & want to keep only 2nd one when we click on ADD TO CART.

current code :

```
<?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>

<button onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

I tried replacing `onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"` but still Product is adding to cart when we click on ADD TO CART.

**But we dont want to add Product to cart when we click on ADD TO CART**

**Edit** : skin/frontend/base/default/js/msrp.js

```
var cartButton = $('map-popup-button');
            if (typeof this.cartLink != 'undefined') {
                if (typeof productAddToCartForm == 'undefined' || this.notUseForm) {
                    Catalog.Map.setGotoView(cartButton, this.cartLink);
                    productAddToCartForm = $('product_addtocart_form_from_popup');
                } else {
                    if (this.qty) {
                        productAddToCartForm.qty = this.qty;
                    }
                    cartButton.stopObserving('click');
                    cartButton.href = this.cartLink;
                    Event.observe(cartButton, 'click', function(event) {
                        productAddToCartForm.action = this.href;
                        productAddToCartForm.submit(this);
                    });
                }
                productAddToCartForm.action = this.cartLink;
                var productField = $('map-popup-product-id');
                productField.value = this.product_id;
                $(cartButton).show();
                $$('.additional-addtocart-box').invoke('show');
            } else {
                $(cartButton).hide();
                $$('.additional-addtocart-box').invoke('hide');
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite controllers function responsible for add product to cart
magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php :: addAction

Comment: Thanks for reply, is `addAction` function is responsible for both feature 1 & 2 , that i posted in question ?

Comment: You want to have row with item in cart but You don't want to display it on frontend? Can't You remove or block cart / remove cart slider?

Comment: yes i want to have `row with item in cart` , but dont want to add item to `cart` - i am planning to do this customization for another button say `ADD to cart1` because for [this links requirement](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162549/save-image-in-quotes-when-we-click-on-button)

Comment: I answered there. I hope it helps;)